# Google drive API v3 сервисный акаунт, как переместить файл в корзину

Tags: php, google-drive

Есть функция через которую файл удаляется в общей папке на гугл диске через сервисный аккаунт, рабочий вариант, но файл не отображается в корзине самого владельца этой общей папки, в истории указано что файл перемещен в корзину владельца файла, владельцем файла является сервисный аккаунт. Так же загрузка файлов осуществляется через сервисный аккаунт, которому открыт доступ к общей папке одного из аккаунтов gsuite, этот функционал работает, файлы загружаются, но при удалении файл почему-то не отображается в корзине владельца общей папки.

Код (PHP) через который файл перемещается в корзину:

```
protected function drive_delete_file_lead($file_id, $folder_id, $base_drive_folder_id) { 
    try {
        $files = new Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile();
        $files->setTrashed(true);
        //$opts = ['removeParents' => $folder_id];
        $opts = ['addParents' => $folder_id];
        $this->service->files->update($file_id, $files, $opts);
        return true;
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        return 'GoogleDrive error: ' . $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Как я понял по документации файлы которые пренадлежат сервисному акаунт не перемещаются в корзину и удаляются навсегда. Возможно в моем коде какаято ошибка, или неверный метод перемещения файла в корзину.